# is there a compatible TCL environment variable for cygwin and python idle

Tags: python, cygwin, tcl

Idle stopped working after installing cygwin and after some troubleshooting (on windows if its not obvious), it looks like the issue is with a TCL library. They both use an environment variable to locate tcl. when I installed cygwin, it overwrote the variable to a different (and incompatible to python) version. Now I figure I can just change the variable, but it seems kind of a hassle to switch between them all of the time. Does anyone have a good solution to this? (besides not using cygwin or something...)

Comment: Oh crikey! Two things fighting over poor old Tcl, and there's a fair chance they're both behind the times anyway. :-) For *reference* only, the *supported* version *should* be 8.5.9…

Answer (score 0):

If you could change the variable, you know already which it is, and to which value it is set. Would you kindly share this information, maybe someone can make an educated guess?

Comment: basically cygwin has a tcl library in its libs directory and so does python. to use idle i switch the variable into the python one.